# double select statement issue, multiple rows returned , subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server, select, subquery

ok, here it goes, I have 3 tables:

```
accounts             ( account_id,      employee_id, account_name )
projects             ( project_id,      project_name )
project_distribution ( distribution_id, employee_id, project_id )
```

What I want to do is to return the project names from the project table if i have the project ids from the project_distribution table.So , let's assume that i have employee_id, i'm going into project_distribution and do a select, I get 2 values for project_id ,id 1 and 2, how can i return the project_names for these two IDs without doing 2 querys or statemens or how are they correctly called, here is my bad select statement.

```
SELECT project_name
FROM   projects
WHERE  project_id = ( SELECT project_id
                      FROM   project_distribution
                      WHERE  employee_id = ( SELECT employee_id
                                             FROM accounts
                                             WHERE account_name = 'tbogdan'
                                            )
                    );
```

oufcorse I will get 2 values from project_distribution,and a "Subquery returned more than 1 value" error  how can I fix this , and make it work?
If more info is needed, please ask...sorry for vague description...

Comment: please spend a couple of moments formatting everything to make it easier to read and digest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
SELECT projects.project_name 
FROM projects
INNER JOIN project_distribution ON (projects.project_id = project_distribution.project_id)
INNER JOIN accounts ON (project_distribution.employee_id = accounts.employee_id)
WHERE accounts.employee_id = 'tbogdan'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the IN keyword instead of equals in the project_distribution subquery.

```
SELECT project_name
FROM   projects
WHERE  project_id = ( SELECT project_id
                      FROM   project_distribution
                      WHERE  employee_id IN ( SELECT employee_id
                                             FROM accounts
                                             WHERE account_name = 'tbogdan'
                                            )
                    );
```

You can test your query without the subqueries by manually inputting the values you expect to be returned from the subquery:

```
SELECT project_name
FROM   projects
WHERE  project_id IN (1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT projects.project_name
FROM   projects
INNER JOIN project_distribution distrib
    ON projects.project_id = distrib.project_id
INNER JOIN accounts
    ON distrib.employee_id = accounts.employee_id
WHERE accounts.account_name = 'tbogdan';
```

Comment: good information, Will use it in next issues:)), I will need some joins...thank you

Answer (score 0):

EXISTS is also a possibility:

```
SELECT pr.project_name
FROM   projects pr
WHERE  EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM project_distribution pd
    JOIN accounts ac ON ac.employee_id = pd.employee_id
    WHERE ac.account_name = 'tbogdan'
    );
```

The nice thing about exists is that the *inner* correlation names (pd,ac) are not exposed to the main query.